# How to fix Python Tkinter "_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-show"?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

**Currently building a program using Tkinter as a user input to put Username and Password, and for some reason when I try to make the password using the *`show='*'`*, it doesn't work.**

> ```
> #Importing module
> import tkinter as tk
> from tkinter import *
>
> #Window
> root = tk.Tk()  
> root.geometry('330x100') 
>
> #Entry 
> tk.Label(root, text="USERNAME:", font=('April',18)).grid(pady=3,padx =2,row=0)
> tk.Label(root,show='*', text="PASSWORD:",font=('April',18)).grid(pady=3,padx =2,row=1)
> e = tk.Entry(root)
> en = tk.Entry(root)
> e.grid(row=0, column=1)
> en.grid(row=1, column=1)
>          
> #Button 
> ButtonOne = tk.Button(text ="EXIT", command = root.destroy, pady= 3, padx= 2)
> ButtonOne.place (x=180, y=70)
>  
> #End
> root.mainloop()
> ```

Then it returns this error

```
    *PS C:\Users\Dell> & C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe c:/Users/Dell/Desktop/CCS1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\CCS1.py", line 11, in <module>
    tk.Label(root,show='*', text="PASSWORD:",font=('April',18)).grid(pady=3,padx =2,row=1)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3177, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2601, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-show"
PS C:\Users\Dell> *
```

**Can someone please help me with this problem?**

Comment: The `show="*"` is only for `tk.Entry`. You can't use it inside `tk.Label`. You can get that from the error message.

Answer (score 2):

to fix your problem you need to remove `show='*'` from the Label and use it on your Entry like this :

```
tk.Label(root, text="PASSWORD:", font=('April', 18)).grid(pady=3, padx=2, row=1)
en = tk.Entry(root, show="*")
```